# Implementing subtables in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf

We're looking for a way to implement subtables in JSF 1.1.  We cannot use Rich Faces due to the fact that out target server is WebSphere 6.1.  I've tried JSTL and Tomahawk to no avail. Also, our project is using JSP's and not facelets.

Comment: I've a hard time in visualizing "subtables" in plain HTML. Don't you just mean nested tables? Or do you mean colspans/rowspans? Consider posting a plain HTML example how the result should look like.

Comment: Yes, nested tables.  JSTL is out of the question as the nested table must contain JSF controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [nest](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#NestingDatatables) `h:dataTable`s in each other inside a `h:column`. But you actually want to nest another `h:dataTable` inside a **new** row subsequently. There's then no other way to create a single column and put a `h:panelGrid` in it to represent the "main" row and a nested `h:dataTable` to represent the "detail" row. You also need a good shot of CSS to get it all nicely aligned and some smart piece of JavaScript to show/hide the "detail" row.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.orders}" var="order">
    <h:column>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:graphicImage id="expand" value="expand.gif" onclick="toggleDetails(this);" />
            <h:outputText value="#{order.id}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{order.name}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:dataTable id="details" value="#{order.details}" var="detail" style="display: none;">
            <h:column><h:outputText value="#{detail.date}" /></h:column>
            <h:column><h:outputText value="#{detail.description}" /></h:column>
            <h:column><h:outputText value="#{detail.quantity}" /></h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The `toggleDetails()` function can look like (note that it takes JSF generated client ID into account):

```
function toggleDetails(image) {
    var detailsId = image.id.substring(0, image.id.lastIndexOf(':')) + ':details';
    var details = document.getElementById(detailsId);
    if (details.style.display == 'none') {
        details.style.display = 'block';
        image.src = 'collapse.gif';
    } else {
        details.style.display = 'none';
        image.src = 'expand.gif';
    }
}
```

Comment: BalusC, great example and I'm very close.  The only problem I have remaining is how to align the headers for the main table.  Since the main table only has one column it looks tricky - also the main title headers cannot repeat.  The nested table is rather easy as each column can be assigned a facet tag.

Comment: Put another `h:panelGrid` inside `f:facet` of the outer `h:column` and throw some magic CSS in to make it look right.